# One Function of Two Random Variable

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I wonder how to implement below derivation in wolfram mathematica. I want to see integrate results like below picture. Can you help. I used "TransformedDistribution" but it shows only distribution name.

Picture from : Athanasios Papoulis - Unnikrishna Pillai - Probability, Random Variables and Stochastic Processes  -McGraw-Hill Europe (2002) page 190.

[image: z=x+y]

Comment: Mathematica is not designed to give step-by-step solutions. In general, the algorithms that it uses are not the ones that you might use when doing a problem. For simpler problems, the `WolframAlpha` command may offer a step-by-step solution. `f[z_] = PDF[TransformedDistribution[x^2 + y^2,
   {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, σ],
    y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, σ]}], z]`

Comment: If you need the steps to the integration, then you might consider Rubi (https://rulebasedintegration.org/).  There's also a missing "-" in the first equation:  $(z-y^2+y^2)/2\sigma^2$ should be $-(z-y^2+y^2)/2\sigma^2$.

Comment: Have you tried Rubi?